# Choosing an efficient data structure to find rhymes

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, dictionary, tree

I've been working on a program that reads in a whole dictionary, and utilizes the WordNet from CMU that splits every word to its pronunciation.

The goal is to utilize the dictionary to find the best rhymes and alliterations of a given word, given the number of syllables in the word we need to find and its part of speech.

I've decided to use `std::map<std::string, vector<Sound> >` and `std::multimap<int, std::string>` where the map maps each word in the dictionary to its pronunciation in a vector, and the multimap is returned from a function that finds all the words that rhyme with a given word.

The `int` is the number of syllables of the corresponding word, and the `string` holds the word.

I've been working on the efficiency, but can't seem to get it to be more efficient than `O(n)`. The way I'm finding all the words that rhyme with a given word is

```
vector<string> *rhymingWords = new vector<string>;
for (iterator it : map<std::string, vector<Sound> >) {
    if(rhymingSyllables(word, it.first) >= 1 && it.first != word) {
        rhymingWords->push_back(it.first);
    }
}
return rhymingWords;
```

And when I find the best rhyme for a word (a word that rhymes the most syllables with the given word), I do

```
vector<string> rhymes = *getAllRhymes(rhymesWith);
int x = 0;
for (string s : rhymes) {
    if (countSyllables(s) == numberOfSyllables) {
        int a = rhymingSyllables(s, rhymesWith);
        if (a > x) {
            maxRhymes = thisRhyme;
            bestRhyme = s;
        }
    }
}
return bestRhyme;
```

The drawback is the `O(n)` access time in terms of the number of words in the dictionary. I'm thinking of ideas to drop this down to `O(log n)` , but seem to hit a dead end every time. I've considered using a tree structure, but can't work out the specifics.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

The `rhymingSyllables` function is implemented  as such:

```
int syllableCount = 0;
if((soundMap.count(word1) == 0) || (soundMap.count(word2) == 0)) {
    return 0;
}
vector<Sound> &firstSounds = soundMap.at(word1), &secondSounds = soundMap.at(word2);
for(int i = firstSounds.size() - 1, j = secondSounds.size() - 1; i >= 0 && j >= 0; --i, --j){
    if(firstSounds[i] != secondSounds[j]) return syllableCount;
    else if(firstSounds[i].isVowel()) ++syllableCount;
}
return syllableCount;
```

P.S.
The `vector<Sound>` is the pronunciation of the word, where `Sound` is a class that contains every different pronunciation of a morpheme in English: i.e,
`AA vowel AE  vowel AH  vowel AO  vowel AW  vowel AY  vowel B   stop CH  affricate D   stop DH  fricative EH  vowel ER  vowel EY  vowel F   fricative G   stop HH  aspirate IH  vowel IY  vowel JH  affricate K   stop L   liquid M   nasal N   nasal NG  nasal OW  vowel OY  vowel P   stop R   liquid S   fricative SH  fricative T   stop TH  fricative UH  vowel UW  vowel V   fricative W   semivowel Y   semivowel Z   fricative ZH  fricative`

Comment: The gist of the problem is in rhymingSyllables. How does it work?

Comment: I've added it to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered a hash table?

Comment: So you basically find words that end in exactly the same sequence of sounds, and prioritize them by the number of syllables in their common ending? That's a very rough approach to rhyming, but if you want to explore it, you probably want the *trie* data structure built on reversed words.

Comment: Maybe you can post your solution here to help other people having same or similar question?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could group the morphemes that will be matched during rhyming and compare not the vectors of morphemes, but vectors of associated groups. Then you can sort the dictionary once and get a logarithmic search time.

After looking at rhymingSyllables implementation, it seems that you convert words to sounds, and then match any vowels to each other, and match other sounds only if they are the same. So applying advice above, you could introduce an extra auxiliary sound 'anyVowel', and then during dictionary building convert each word to its sound, replace all vowels with 'anyVowel' and push that representation to dictionary. Once you're done sort the dictionary. When you want to search a rhyme for a word - convert it to the same representation and do a binary search on the dictionary, first by last sound as a key, then by previous and so on. This will give you m*log(n) worst case complexity, where n is dictionary size and m is word length, but typically it will terminate faster.

You could also exploit the fact that for best rhyme you consider words only with certain syllable numbers, and maintain a separate dictionary per each syllable count. Then you count number of syllables in word you look rhymes for, and search in appropriate dictionary. Asymptotically it doesn't give you any gain, but a speedup it gives may be useful in your application.

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about this and I could probably suggest an approach to an algorithm.

I would maybe first take the dictionary and divide it into multiple buckets or batches. Where each batch represents the number of syllables each word has. The traversing of the vector to store into different buckets should be linear as you are traverse a large vector of strings. From here since the first bucket will have all words of 1 syllable there is nothing to do at the moment so you can skip to bucket two and each bucket after will need to take each word and separate the syllables of each word. So if you have say 25 buckets, where you know the first few and the last few are not going to hold many words their time shouldn't be significant and should be done first, however the buckets in the middle that have say 3-5 or 3-6 syllables in length will be the largest to do so you could run each of these buckets on a separate thread if their size is over a certain amount and have them run in parallel. Now once you are done; each bucket should return a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Word>>` where your structure might look like this:

```
 enum SpeechSound {
     SS_AA,
     SS_AE,
     SS_...

     SS_ZH
 };

 enum SpeechSoundType {
     ASPIRATE,
     ...
     VOWEL
 };

 struct SyllableMorpheme  {
     SpeechSound sound;
     SpeechSoundType type;         
 };

 class Word {
 public:

 private:
     std::string m_strWord;

     // These Two Containers Should Match In Size! One String For Each
     // Syllable & One Matching Struct From Above Containing Two Enums.
     std::vector<std::string> m_vSyllables
     std::vector<SyllableMorpheme> m_vMorphemes;

 public:
     explicit Word( const std::string& word );

     std::string getWord() const;

     std::string getSyllable( unsigned index ) const;
     unsigned getSyllableCount() const;

     SyllableMorpheme getMorhpeme( unsigned index ) const;

     bool operator==( const ClassObj& other ) const;
     bool operator!=( const ClassObj& other ) const;

 private:
     Word( const Word& c ); // Not Implemented
     Word& operator=( const Word& other ) const; // Not Implemented
 };
```

This time you will now have new buckets or vectors of shared pointers of these class objects. Then you can easily write a function to traverse through each bucket or even multiple buckets since the buckets will have the same signature only a different amount of syllables. Remember; each bucket should already be sorted alphabetically since we only added them in by the syllable count and never changed the order that was read in from the dictionary.

Then with this you can easily compare if two words are equal or not while checking For Matching Syllables and Morphemes. And these are contained in `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Word>>`. So you don't have to worry about memory clean up as much either.

The idea is to use linear search, separation and comparison as much as possible; yet if your container gets too large, then create buckets and run in parallel multiple threads, or maybe use a hash table if it will suite your needs.

Another possibility with this class structure is that you could even add more to it later on if you wanted or needed to such as another std::vector for its definitions, and another `std::vector<string>` for its part of speech {noun, verb, etc.} You could even add in other `vector<string>` for things such as homonyms, homophomes and even a `vector<string>` for a list of all words that rhyme with it.

Now for your specific task of finding the best matching rhyme you may find that some words may end up having a list of Words that would all be considered a Best Match or Fit! Due to this you wouldn't want to store or return a single string, but rather a vector of strings!

Case Example:

```
To Too Two Blue Blew Hue Hew Knew New,  
Bare Bear Care Air Ayre Heir Fair Fare There Their They're
Plain, Plane, Rain, Reign, Main, Mane, Maine
```

Yes these are all single syllable rhyming words, but as you can see there are many cases where there are multiple valid answers, not just a single best case match. This is something that does need to be taken into consideration.